# Converting timestamp to date in angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular and I dont have much ideas about directive. I need to create a directive which will take a timestamp as an input and display the same in hours:minutes:seconds format (in a dropdown). If someone changes the value of hours, minutes or seconds from the screen then the timestamp should also change. I am able to convert the timestamp and show it as hours, minutes and seconds but I am unable to get back the timestamp when the user changes the value from the screen.

Comment: Can you try providing a fiddler or plunkr to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Okay, I will try to create a plunkr

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check [ask] for more information about how to get the most out of your questions.  As Pratik suggested, it's best to provide your code and any specific error messages you are receiving to facilitate readers in answering your question.  Also, you can [edit] your answer and post a [mcve] of what you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the concept of using ng-model in a directive. I am not sure how you are passing the timestamp to the model but if you use ng-model then you push a custom $formatter in your ng-model controller to convert your timestamp to hours, mins and seconds (using whatever logic suits your domain) and then render the same in your view. For converting the date back to timestamp you need to push a $parser which will convert your date time to timestamp. However you will have put a $watch on your viewValue to trigger the parser whenever the user changes the value from the screen. I have created a fiddler for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/oavzar9j/).

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive("timeDir", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A/E",
    template: "Min - <input type='text' ng-model='time.min'></input><br/>Sec - <input type='text' ng-model='time.sec'></input>",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
        var mins = parseInt(modelValue / 60);
        var secs = modelValue % 60;
        return {
          min: mins,
          sec: secs
        }
      });

      ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
        scope.time = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
        var totalSec = parseInt(parseInt(viewValue.min * 60) + parseInt(viewValue.sec));
        return totalSec;
      });

      scope.$watch('time', function() {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.time);
      }, true);
    }
  }
});
```

Please note that I have converted the timestamp to min:second only.

Comment: @KobiCohen :-). Actually I had something of a similar situation but it was much more complicated and I found the usage of ng-model in directives very helpful. Your answer is much more simpler and compact. Upvoted that solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the date filter:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dateInput">
{{dateInput | date : 'hh:mm:ss'}}
```

The dateInput model doesn't change and is still the pure timestamp that the user entered. And you can present the data as date with the date filter very easily. (you can attach it to a dropdown just the same way)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the problem is that the timestamp that I am receiving from my API is a customly generated timestamp. So I have a different logic to convert timestamp to date. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: just make your own filter, tutorial from the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: OKay i will try to use this.